# PHP returns a result from mysql, but if I while loop the result, nothing shows

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code:

```
<?php
    require('...........');
    require('................');

    $search_query = strip_tags(substr($_POST['search_query'], 0, 60));
    $region_query = strip_tags(substr($_POST['region_choice'], 0, 2));
    $class_query  = $_POST['class_choice'];
    $quick_search = strip_tags(substr($_POST['quick_search'], 0, 1));
             ;

    # setup database connection
    $db_ok = 1;
    $dbh = @mysql_connect($GLOBALS['database']['hs'], $GLOBALS['database']['un'],$GLOBALS['database']['pw']);
    if (! $dbh) {
        $db_ok = 0;
    }
    $dbh_selected = @mysql_select_db($GLOBALS['database']['db'], $dbh);
    if (! $dbh_selected) {
        $db_ok = 0;
    }

    if ($db_ok == 1) {
        $query_addition = "";

    if ($region_query > 0) {
        $query_addition = " AND `location` = \"$region_query\" ";
    }   

    if ($class_query > 0) {
        $query_addition .= " AND `class` = \"$class_query\" ";
    }

    $query  = "SELECT ID,date_active,title,location,environment,specialism FROM ";
    $query .= $GLOBALS['database']['jobs_table'] . " WHERE `date_active` < CURDATE()     AND `date_inactive` > CURDATE() 
    $query_addition AND `description` LIKE \"%$search_query%\"  ORDER BY `ID`";
    mysql_real_escape_string($query); 
    //mysql_set_charset('utf-8', $query);
    $result = mysql_query($query,$dbh);

    $table_content = "";
    $row_count = 0;

    if ($result) {  
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $id    = $row[0];
            $loc = stripslashes($row[3]);
            $title = htmlentities(stripslashes($row[2]));           
            $env   = htmlentities(stripslashes($row[4]));           
            $spec  = htmlentities(stripslashes($row[5]));   

            if ($row_count % 2 == 0) {
                $table_content .= "<tr>";
            } else {    
                $table_content .= "<tr class=\"mellon\">";
            }   
            $table_content .= "<td><a href=\"?p=Vacature&ID=$id\" abbr=\"". $title . "\" title=\"" . $title ."\">" . $title . "</a></td>";
            $table_content .= "<td>" . get_location($dbh,$loc) . "</td>";
            $table_content .= "<td>" . $env . "</td>";
            $table_content .= "<td>" . $spec . "</td>";
            $table_content .= "</tr>\n";
            $row_count++;
            if ($row_count == 20) {
                break;
            }           
        }
    }

    if ($row_count > 0) {
        print " 
        <p>U heeft gezocht op: <b>$search_query</b></p>
        <p>Hieronder vindt u een overzicht van gevonden vacatures met een maximum aantal van 20. Er zijn in totaal $row_count vacatures gevonden.</p>
        <table class=\"table_layout\">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Titel</th><th>Regio</th><th>Werkomgeving</th><th>Specialisme</th>
            </tr>
            $table_content 
        </tbody></table>";

    } else {
        print " 
        <p>U heeft gezocht op: <b>$search_query</b></p>
        <p><h4>Helaas heeft uw zoekopdracht geen resultaten opgeleverd</h4> </p>
        " ;
    }

} else {
    print "
    <p>U heeft gezocht op: <b>$search_query</b></p>
    <p>Het zoeken is mislukt..</p>
    ";
}   
?>
```

I've tried everything, if I var_dump I get that he has a result, Only the while loop doesn't seem to work. By the way it only doesn't work when I use a special character like ö, of I use the o it will work. I've tried everything from htmlspecialchar, htmlentities and so on.
I also tried to convert the special chars with a str_replace and strtr. Please help, would be thankful

Comment: what does mysql_num_rows($resultset) return on your result set ?

Comment: Worth mentioning by the way is that when I run the code in mysql it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a mysql_real_escape_string on the entire query is the WRONG way to do things. You escape INDIVIDUAL strings you insert, not the whole query. By escaping the whole query, you're breaking it.

```
$x = mysql_real_escape_string("Miles O'Brien");
$sql = "SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE username='$x'";
```

will produce

```
SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE username='Miles O\'Brien';
```

by comparison, you version would product

```
SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE username=\'Miles O\'Brien\';
```

and completely fail.

Comment: thanks guys, but i still have the problem, when I try to search with 'ö', this returns no results, while when I search with a 'o' instead, it works. The string however is when f.e. searching with 'zorgcoördinator' 16chars long and when searching with 'zorgcoordinator' 15 chars. @marc-b

Comment: I adjusted the mysql_real_escape string THANKS. The problem which I had is solved now, I used utf8_decode which worked! Thanks again all for looking at my problem

Answer (score 2):

You can't run `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the entire query, only on query parameters:

```
$query .= $GLOBALS['database']['jobs_table'] . " WHERE `date_active` < CURDATE()
    AND `date_inactive` > CURDATE()"
    . mysql_real_escape_string($query_addition) . " AND `description`
    LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($search_query)"%'  ORDER BY `ID`";
```

The quotes in your query will get escaped if you use it on the whole thing.

Comment: thanks guys, but i still have the problem, when I try to search with 'ö', this returns no results, while when I search with a 'o' instead, it works. The string however is when f.e. searching with 'zorgcoördinator' 16chars long and when searching with 'zorgcoordinator' 15 chars. @tandu

Comment: I adjusted the mysql_real_escape string THANKS. The problem which I had is solved now, I used utf8_decode which worked! Thanks again all for looking at my problem

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using the mysql_real_escape_string function wrong. You are supposed to use it on the variables you put into the mysql query, not the whole query.

Try this:

```
$query_addition = "";
if ($region_query > 0) {
    $query_addition .= " AND `location` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($class_query)."' ";
}   

if ($class_query > 0) {
    $query_addition .= " AND `class` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($class_query)."' ";
}

$query  = "SELECT ID,date_active,title,location,environment,specialism FROM ";
$query .= $GLOBALS['database']['jobs_table'] . " WHERE `date_active` < CURDATE()     AND `date_inactive` > CURDATE() 
        $query_addition AND `description` LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($search_query)."'  ORDER BY `ID`";

$result = mysql_query($query,$dbh);
```

Does it help?

Comment: thanks guys, but i still have the problem, when I try to search with 'ö', this returns no results, while when I search with a 'o' instead, it works. The string however is when f.e. searching with 'zorgcoördinator' 16chars long and when searching with 'zorgcoordinator' 15 chars. @sonny

Comment: I adjusted the mysql_real_escape string THANKS. The problem which I had is solved now, I used utf8_decode which worked! Thanks again all for looking at my problem

Answer (score 1):

The query returned no rows.

Print your query out and run it in phpmyadmin/console to be sure and then alter the query to get the query that will return desired rows.

To sort things out you have to separate your task into smaller sub-tasks.
The algorithm is quite simple

1. Put PHP aside anad work with SQL only in console/phpmyadmin.
   Work your query out until make it works. 
   **Write this query down** for the future reference.
2. Get back to PHP to assemble the query from
   Print this query out and compare with one from the (1)
   Work your code out until you have 2 queries **identical**
3. Finally, run it with PHP.

PS. I am aware that `mysql_real_escape_string($query);` was added by accident among other attempts to make it work but anyway you have to remove that line.